# what is the lambda(^) operator in git

Tags: git

I am trying to find the difference in commit history between two branches. I have found two options, out of the infinite possibilities in git, as of yet :

```
git log mynewbranch --not mymasterbranch

git log mynewbranch ^mymasterbranch
```

Are both these commands exactly the same? In my tests, they provide the exact same output.

Also I am guessing the ^ operator has some general meaning in git that can be applied in many different contexts to many different commands as i have seen it being used as such. So what does the ^ actually indicate?

Comment: `^` means the first parent commit.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: *as a suffix*, `^` means first-parent (unless followed by numbers, e.g., `refs/stash^2` means 2nd-parent).  This is using `^` as a prefix, though.

Comment: @torek In that case, my previous comment is wrong in this question's context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two commands listed by you **are** identical.

Refer to [Revision Selection](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html) in the Git book:

> Git allows you to do this by using either the `^` character or `--not`
>   before any reference from which you don’t want to see reachable
>   commits. Thus these three commands are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $ git log refA..refB
> $ git log ^refA refB
> $ git log refB --not refA
> ```

Answer (score 2):

> perhaps you want to specify more than two branches to indicate your revision, such as seeing what commits are in any of several branches that aren’t in the branch you’re currently on. Git allows you to do this by using either the ^ character or --not before any reference from which you don’t want to see reachable commits. Thus these three commands are equivalent:

```
$ git log refA..refB
$ git log ^refA refB
$ git log refB --not refA
```

Source: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection

Comment: Note also that `^` binds to its one branch, e.g., `^br1 ^br2 master` means "not `br1`, and not `br2`, but do use `master`", while `--not` is a bit more global: you could write `--not br1 br2 --not master` to mean the same thing.  The `--not` remains in effect for both `br1` and `br2`, and then the second `--not` cancels the first `--not`, so that the `master` is a positive, instead of negative, reference.